# Como exibir o estado em um geochart?

Tags: google-charts

Estou a exibir um geochart ao nível de estado. Ao configurar com a região do Brasil funciona, como podem ver abaixo, porém não com o código do estado, por exemplo: `BR-SP`

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['geochart', 'table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Views'],
    ['BR-AL', 300],
    ['BR-SP', 300],
    ['BR-RJ', 400]

  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    region: 'BR',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#acb2b9', '#2f3f4f']
    }
  };

  geochart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

A nível de estado:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['geochart', 'table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Views'],
    ['Sao Paulo', 300],
    ['Campinas', 300],

  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    region: 'BR-SP',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#acb2b9', '#2f3f4f']
    }
  };

  geochart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Amigão, ai está, da forma que você quer, ele usa que quando dá um clique ele muda de State para City e coloca em Markers.

Dê uma olhada no que eu fiz aqui, voce vai conseguir pegar.

Fiz com base no dele, Boa Sorte, Caso não seja isso que queira, comente ai me explicando melhor :D

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
      'packages': ['geochart', 'table']
  });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
  
  function drawRegionsMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      // Results For US States
      // State format must be "BR-**"
      // US represents region, while the ** section represents the individual state 
      ['State', 'Views'],
          ['BR-SP', 300],
          ['BR-PE', 300],
          ['BR-AM', 400]
  
      ]);
  
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data)
      view.setColumns([0, 1])
  
      var options = {
          region: 'BR',
          resolution: 'provinces',
          width: 556,
          height: 347
      };
  
      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
  
      var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      var options = {
          region: 'BR',
          resolution: 'provinces',
          width: 556,
          height: 347,
          colorAxis: {
              colors: ['#acb2b9', '#2f3f4f']
          } // orange to blue 
      };
      google.visualization.events.addListener(geochart, 'regionClick', function (eventData) {
          // maybe you want to change the data table here...
          options['region'] = eventData.region;
          options['resolution'] = 'provinces';
          options['displayMode'] = 'markers';
  
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          // Add Results for Individual State
          // Format needs to match what is below so that it locates the correct position
          // Additional information can be added to array
          // Uses first value in 2nd column to determine scale for markers
          // Use AJAX to load this on regionClick
          ['City', 'Views'],
              ['Recife, PE', 200],
              ['Manaus, AM', 300],
              ['Santos, SP', 400],
              ['Campinas, SP', 400],
  
          ]);
  
          geochart.draw(data, options);
          var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
          table.draw(data, null);
  
      });
      geochart.draw(data, options);
  
  };
```

```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

        <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: E o "Zoom" a nível de estado? O que preciso é que quando clicar em um, ele dê zoom no estado e apareça os marcadores.

Comment: amigão dei uma pesquisada rápida aqui no api e no grupo do google charts, e diz assim:
"Not all countries have province-level maps in the GeoCharts, and it looks like Brazil is one of the ones that doesn't have them.  In order to zoom in on the region, you would have to use Google Maps".

Básicamente o brasil não está com esse tipo de zoom, pode testar no region, coloque: region: 'BR-SP', ele da erro.
Mas se colocar por ex: region: 'US-AL' ele vai dar o zoom.

Infelizmente oque resta a ser feito é ou usar o google maps ou simplesmente usar markers.

O google infelizmente não atualizou para nós

Comment: E pelo visto está assim desde 2012.

Fonte: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/G4MObm_ztXY

Para usar google maps: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map

Answer (score 1):

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['geochart', 'table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Views'],
    ['Sao Paulo', 300],
    ['Campinas', 300],

  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
        region: 'BR',
        displayMode: 'markers',
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        colorAxis: {
            colors: ['#acb2b9', '#2f3f4f']
        }
    };

  geochart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Andrey, o que estou tentando fazer é que mostre apenas o estado no chart. Um exemplo é quando você clica em um estado do US nesse link: https://leachcreative.com/demos/us-geochart/